# How to draw transparent arc with line corner end in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I want to draw transparent arc after color gradient radius end. It sound confusing. I have progress bar in which I have end the line at `X` position. After that I want to show transparent arc space at `X` position with Line Gradient. I am trying to use `drawArc`, but it's not working correctly.

```
@Composable
fun DrawProgressBar() {
    val activity = LocalContext.current as AppCompatActivity
    val rangeComposition = RangeComposition()
    val itemLst = rangeComposition.bpExplained
    val boxSize = 30.dp
    val brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(listOf(Color.Red, Color.Blue))
    val progressBarPointer = rangeComposition.findReadingWithPointer(142, 90).second
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .height(height = boxSize)
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            val strokeWidth = 8.dp
            val canvasWidth = size.width
            val canvasHeight = size.height
            val strokeWidthPx = density.run { strokeWidth.toPx() }
            drawLine(
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = canvasHeight / 2),
                end = Offset(x = canvasWidth, y = canvasHeight / 2),
                color = Color.Gray,
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx,
                cap = StrokeCap.Round,
            )
            val progressBarPointerInPixel = (progressBarPointer / 100f) * canvasWidth
            activity.logE("progressBarPointerInPixel $progressBarPointerInPixel")
            drawLine(
                brush = brush,
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = canvasHeight / 2),
                end = Offset(x = progressBarPointerInPixel, y = canvasHeight / 2),
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx,
                cap = StrokeCap.Round,
            )
            drawArc(
                topLeft = Offset(x = progressBarPointerInPixel, y = canvasHeight / 2),
                size = Size(8.dp.toPx(), strokeWidthPx),
                color = Color.Cyan,
                startAngle = -90f,
                sweepAngle = 180f,
                useCenter = true
            )
            itemLst.forEachIndexed { index, rangeItem ->
                val endPointInPixel = (rangeItem.endPoint / 100f) * canvasWidth
                if (index != itemLst.lastIndex) {
                    drawLine(
                        start = Offset(x = endPointInPixel, y = 0F),
                        end = Offset(x = endPointInPixel, y = boxSize.toPx()),
                        color = Color.Black,
                        strokeWidth = 4.dp.toPx(),
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

You can find the source code of [RangeComposition.kt](https://github.com/vivek-modi/QueueApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/queueapplication/RangeComposition.kt).

**UPDATE**

After [@GabrieleMariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti) mention code I tried with white color and I see that there is white tiny vertical bar is there

```
fun DrawProgressBar() {
    val activity = LocalContext.current as AppCompatActivity
    val rangeComposition = RangeComposition()
    val itemLst = rangeComposition.bpExplained
    val boxSize = 30.dp
    val brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(listOf(Color.Red, Color.Blue))
    val progressBarPointer = rangeComposition.findReadingWithPointer(142, 90).second
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .height(height = boxSize)
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            val strokeWidth = 8.dp
            val canvasWidth = size.width
            val canvasHeight = size.height
            val strokeWidthPx = density.run { strokeWidth.toPx() }
            val pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(canvasHeight / 19, canvasHeight / 19), 0f)
            drawLine(
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = canvasHeight / 2),
                end = Offset(x = canvasWidth, y = canvasHeight / 2),
                color = Color.Gray,
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx,
                cap = StrokeCap.Round,
            )
            val progressBarPointerInPixel = (progressBarPointer / 100f) * canvasWidth
            drawLine(
                color = Color.White,
                start = Offset(x = progressBarPointerInPixel, y = canvasHeight / 2),
                end = Offset(x = progressBarPointerInPixel + strokeWidthPx / 2, y = canvasHeight / 2),
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx,
            )
            drawLine(
                brush = brush,
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = canvasHeight / 2),
                end = Offset(x = progressBarPointerInPixel, y = canvasHeight / 2),
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx,
                cap = StrokeCap.Round,
            )
            drawArc(
                topLeft = Offset(x = progressBarPointerInPixel, y = canvasHeight / 2 - strokeWidthPx / 2),
                size = Size(strokeWidthPx, strokeWidthPx),
                color = Color.White,
                startAngle = -90f,
                sweepAngle = 180f,
                useCenter = true
            )
            itemLst.forEachIndexed { index, rangeItem ->
                val endPointInPixel = (rangeItem.endPoint / 100f) * canvasWidth
                if (index != itemLst.lastIndex) {
                    drawLine(
                        start = Offset(x = endPointInPixel, y = 0F),
                        end = Offset(x = endPointInPixel, y = boxSize.toPx()),
                        color = Color.Black,
                        strokeWidth = 1.2.dp.toPx(),
                        pathEffect = pathEffect
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your arc you have to change the `topLeft` offset considering also the height offset due to the `strokeWidthPx`. Something like:

```
topLeft = Offset(x = progressBarPointerInPixel, y = canvasHeight / 2 - strokeWidthPx/2),
```

Also you should add also a line from `progressBarPointerInPixel` to `progressBarPointerInPixel + strokeWidthPx/2` due to the rounded corners.

Something like:

```
    drawLine(
      //gray line
    )

    drawLine(
        color = Color.Cyan,
        start = Offset(x = progressBarPointerInPixel , y = canvasHeight / 2),
        end = Offset(x = progressBarPointerInPixel + strokeWidthPx/2, y = canvasHeight / 2),
        strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx,
    )

    drawLine(
        brush = brush,
        start = Offset(x = 0f, y = canvasHeight / 2),
        end = Offset(x = progressBarPointerInPixel, y = canvasHeight / 2),
        strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx,
        cap = StrokeCap.Round,
    )

    drawArc(
        topLeft = Offset(x = progressBarPointerInPixel, y = canvasHeight / 2 - strokeWidthPx/2),
        size = Size(strokeWidthPx,strokeWidthPx),
        color = Color.Cyan,
        startAngle = -90f,
        sweepAngle = 180f,
        useCenter = true
    )
```

[image]

To achieve a transparent arc you can add the `blendMode = BlendMode.DstOut` to line+arc.It also requires to apply an `alpha !=1F` to the `Canvas` with `graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.99f)`
Check the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlendMode) for more details about the blendMode.

```
Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.99f)
    ) {
       
    drawLine(
       //gray line
    )

    
    drawLine(
        //...
        color = Color.Cyan,
        blendMode = BlendMode.DstOut
    )

    drawLine(
       //gradient
    )

    drawArc(
        blendMode = BlendMode.DstOut
    )

}
```

Comment: your code add the `arc` after the line. But we add Transparent color it showing me behind grey color. this is separate question should I open for this?

Comment: @VivekModi It is quite complex to achieve a transparent section here. Do you really need a transparent arc or is an arc with the same color of the backgroud around the bar enough for you?

Comment: I think background around car will be enough and it's working as expected. I put the `arc` in white color and there is very tiny straight line vertical. Can we remove that one?

Comment: I added White color in `arc` and added code in **UPDATE** section.

Comment: I've to understand why there is this thin border due to the gray line

Comment: Please let me know if you find the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: @VivekModi added the code to achieve the transparent section. I've to understand why there is the thin border.

Comment: No problem. @GabrieleMariotti thanks a million for support. Please let me know if you find something.